# Linux low profile image to run Virtual Box

Tags: linux

I want a Linux image which can use low resources (RAM & CPU) and is capable of running:

```
1. Virtual Box  
2. A browser
```

Actually my system does not have enough memory to run Windows Server in Virtual Box so I need that solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Suse Studio](http://susestudio.com) is fine when need to customize the Linux image.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to configure the kernel as you wish. By default, so many services/resources come with Linux. Which eats most of memory and CPU time.

For compiling Linux kernel pls refer http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html

If you wish to reduce your file system size then plz refere http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bootdisk-HOWTO/buildroot.html

Comment: It is very hard for me to do the Linux compiling. Please suggest any easy way.